# Map classnames to separate arrays using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, tagging

Let's say we have the following html:

```
 <ul id="portfolio-list" class="clearfix span-24">

  <li class="2012#foo bar car#cat_1">item 1 <br /></li>
  <li class="2011#car foo fly#cat1">item2 <br /></li>
  <li class="2009#car fly swat_car#cat_2">item3<br /></li>
  <li class="2012#bar show car#cat_3">item 4<br /></li>

</ul>
```

and I want to create a map the classes each item to do the following:

1. I'm trying to split the code into three parts
2. output each piece and
3. add them to their own array of values.

Using the following code, it only returns the value from the last list item.

How do I get it to iterate over **ALL** the list items and add the values for each list item.

code follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var splitList = $("#portfolio-list li").map(function() {
        inStringy = $(this).attr("class").split('#');
        list = $(this).attr('class');
        list = list.split("#").join(" ");
        $(this).removeClass();
        var that = $(this);
        $(that).addClass(list);
        return inStringy;
    });

    cla = [];
    yr = inStringy[0]; 
    classListin[classListin.length] = cla + "";
    categoryListin[categoryListin.length] = cat + " ";
    cla = inStringy[1];
    cla = cla.split(" ");
    cat = inStringy[2];
    yearListin = [];
    classListin = [];
    categoryListin = [];
    yearListin[yearListin.length] = yr + "";
    classListin[classListin.length] = cla + "";
    categoryListin[categoryListin.length] = cat + " ";
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please provide an example of the result you'd get from the above HTML.

Comment: This question is geared towards me being able to create a filterable taglist. Here is a link to a more complete take on what I'm trying to accomplish.  You can see that this doesn't output all the tags in the taglist, only the values from the last item.  [link] http://jsbin.com/ujases/194/edit#preview[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globals all over the place!
See comments for explanations.

// answer moved to fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/VyFc8/

Comment: Hi Flo,I really appreciate the answer, but that doesn't quite get us there.

Comment: Hi Flo,I really appreciate the answer, but that doesn't quite get us there.  There are two problems:  1.  The `classesListin = []; ` needs to be `classListin = [];` 2.  This only outputs the first letter of each part, it doesn't output as expected above.  If you add `console.log(classListin);` you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Oh damn, this is what happens when copypasting goes wrong. Check the fiddle in the edited answer.

Comment: really close, but not quite there. how can I get it to properly split each class inside each of three slots?  I will only have one year per item, but will have more than one class and possibly more than one category.  Check out the output from your code if I plug it in: http://jsbin.com/ujases/235/edit#preview

Comment: Hey Flo,  Thanks for all your answers!  I know your time is valuable!  If you link at the last link I included what you'll see are tags generated with multiple class names inseide.  What I'm hoping for is one tag per classname , ie one tag for bar, oin tag for show, one tag for car, one tag for fly, one tag for swat etc....

Comment: Use either "classListin = classListin.concat(cla.split(' '));" or "[].push.apply(classListin, cla.split(' '));" instead of "classListin.push(cla.split(' '));" If duplicates are a problem, you can use jQuery's $.unique to filter the arrays at the end. // Typoed and couldn't edit.

Comment: Flo,  Great Work!  I made a screencast on how to do a simplified version of this at : http://youtu.be/-th-Cu4JsXk  I'd like to do an updated version.  and I'd like to give credit for the solution.  Would you be willing to pm me your website info so I can share it?

Comment: Naw, it's all yours. Not running a site either. Appreciate it, though.

Comment: Hey Flo,  I have made another test, and it doesn't seem to work on a mobile device.  It is at http://jsbin.com/urefor/14/edit#preview  I am dumbfounded.  Works fine on a desktop, but the generated links don't work / aren't clickable on an iphone.